# connection between mpirun command in bash script and MPI code

Tags: mpi, slurm

I'm wondering how it is possible to set a variable in a bash script(slurm) and use that variable in MPI program in C or vice versa.
For example:
In test-mpi.c define int i; ......
Then in bash script use it like this:

```
if (i=o)
  mpirun --map-by ppr:1:socket ./test-mpi
if (i=1)
  mpirun --map-by ppr:1:node ./test-mpi
```

Actually, I want to do one part of my code using ppr:1:socket and the other using ppr:1:node

Also, is there anyway to map a process to a socket in MPI program instead of doing it in bash script?

Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Edit:

Is it ok if I use argc, argv in this way:

```
for (count =0; count < argc; count++){
 if (argv[i] == "state1"){
  for (....)
      do something

for (count =0; count < argc; count++){
 if (argv[i] == "state2"){
  for (....)
      do something
```

Comment: That makes no sense. The variable is only defined after executing the `mpirun` - and then once per process potentially with different values.

Comment: You could add a special command line flag to your C program that forces a specific output, execute that before in the bash script and use that output for a decision. Is that what you want?

Comment: could you give me an example for "add a special command line flag to your C program"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a command line flag to your application like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // argc is the number of arguments, including the executable.
    // so 2 means one argument
    // check if that argument equals "--dump-i"
    if (argc == 2 && 0 == strcmp(argv[1], "--dump-i")) {
        printf("%d", i);
        return 0;
    }
    MPI_Init(NULl, NULL);
    ...
}
```

And in your bash script something like this:

```
i = $(./test-mpi --dump-i)
if [ "$i" == "1" ]; then
    mpirun --map-by ppr:1:socket ./test-mpi
else
    mpirun --map-by ppr:1:node ./test-mpi  
fi
```

(untested)

But I suspect there are much better solutions if you provide more detail on what you actually want to do.

## Edit

To run multiple job steps in parallel in slurm:

```
# Make sure to restrict the resources, such that 
# the entire job has enough to run both steps simultaneously.
# The ampersand launches the jobs in the background such that
# they are not executed sequentially
srun -n ... --map-by ppr:1:socket ./test-mpi --first-loop &
srun -n ... --map-by ppr:1:node ./test-mpi --second-loop &
```

I up to you to implement the command line switch similarly to the example above. You might as well just build to binaries.

## Edit2

Adressing your edit, you cannot compare C-strings with `==`, you need to use `strcmp` or `strncmp`. Fore more complex command line argument parsing take a look at [`getopt_long`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have two for loops in my mpi code and want to do one of them using mpirun --map-by ppr:1:socket ./test-mpi (do the for loop with mapping 1 process per socket) and do the other for loop using mpirun --map-by ppr:1:node ./test-mpi (mapping 1 process per node)

Comment: @Sarah Make a command line parameter to select the loop - and pass the parameter from within the script?

Comment: @Sarah Yes, given sufficient resources, in slurm you can run multiple job steps / `srun` simultaneously by appending `&` in bash. However, your job steps will have separate MPI universes, ranks of the two job steps will not be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. and it is possible to have several mpirun commands in script to run them simultaneously, right? and could u please tell me what the first if condition does? (if(argc==2...))

Comment: @Sarah I  edited my answer to address your additional questions.

Comment: Would u please look at my edited question and let me know if it is ok and how I can use it in bash script?